# Getting all links of a websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi I wanted to create a mini crawler but not use `Scrapy`,

I created something like this:

```
response = requests.get(url)
homepage_link_list = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    if link.get("href"):
        homepage_link_list.append(link.get("href"))


link_list = []
for item in homepage_link_list:
    response = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    for link in soup.findAll("a"):
        if link.get("href"):
            link_list.append(link.get("href"))
```

Although the problem I am encountering is that it only get the the link within the link of webpage, how can I make it do get all the links within all the links of website.

Comment: Video tutorial : [How to Build a Web Crawler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjNm9bazxn8)

Answer (score 9):

You need a recursive call flow. I have written below a class-oriented code. Main points are as follows:

- This implementation is depth-first
- Keep track of already scraped URLs so that we don't scrape them again
- Ignore targets on a page. Eg. if `http://example.com#item1`, ignore `item1`
- If `https://example.com` is already crawled, ignore `http://example.com`
- Discard trailing slash. Eg. if `http://example.com` is already crawled, ignore `http://example.com/`

---

```
''' Scraper.
'''

import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlsplit, SplitResult
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class RecursiveScraper:
    ''' Scrape URLs in a recursive manner.
    '''
    def __init__(self, url):
        ''' Constructor to initialize domain name and main URL.
        '''
        self.domain = urlsplit(url).netloc
        self.mainurl = url
        self.urls = set()

    def preprocess_url(self, referrer, url):
        ''' Clean and filter URLs before scraping.
        '''
        if not url:
            return None

        fields = urlsplit(urljoin(referrer, url))._asdict() # convert to absolute URLs and split
        fields['path'] = re.sub(r'/$', '', fields['path']) # remove trailing /
        fields['fragment'] = '' # remove targets within a page
        fields = SplitResult(**fields)
        if fields.netloc == self.domain:
            # Scrape pages of current domain only
            if fields.scheme == 'http':
                httpurl = cleanurl = fields.geturl()
                httpsurl = httpurl.replace('http:', 'https:', 1)
            else:
                httpsurl = cleanurl = fields.geturl()
                httpurl = httpsurl.replace('https:', 'http:', 1)
            if httpurl not in self.urls and httpsurl not in self.urls:
                # Return URL only if it's not already in list
                return cleanurl

        return None

    def scrape(self, url=None):
        ''' Scrape the URL and its outward links in a depth-first order.
            If URL argument is None, start from main page.
        '''
        if url is None:
            url = self.mainurl

        print("Scraping {:s} ...".format(url))
        self.urls.add(url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        for link in soup.findAll("a"):
            childurl = self.preprocess_url(url, link.get("href"))
            if childurl:
                self.scrape(childurl)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rscraper = RecursiveScraper("http://bbc.com")
    rscraper.scrape()
    print(rscraper.urls)
```

Comment: it's a shame this hasn't been selected as answer yet.

Comment: In `preprocess_url()` under the `else:` block, `httpurl = httpurl.replace('https:', 'http:', 1)` should be `httpurl = httpsurl.replace('https:', 'http:', 1)`.

Comment: If you try to scrape a url like: [https://www.americanexpress.com/hu-hu/](https://www.americanexpress.com/hu-hu/), it will only keep the [https://www.americanexpress.com/](https://www.americanexpress.com/) part of it and scrape all the amex sites globally, but I don't need all the non-hungarian pages. What to add to this code above to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: I added a new answer based on @coder.in.me's code that resolves my other comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the links you want to scrape are not actually links. They could be images. Sorry for writing this answer here actally I dont have much reputation to comment,

Comment: Yes I know, although I want to get all links within link similar to Screaming Frog.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not fetching all the links of the website because it is not recursive​. You're fetching the homepage links and traversing the links available in the content of the homepage links. But, you're not traversing the links you get in the content of those links you just traversed. My advice is you should check out some tree traversal algorithms and develop a scheme of traversal (recursive) according to the algorithm.  The nodes of the trees will represent the links, root node being the link you passed in the beginning.

Comment: Do you have a sample of it?

Comment: Yes. But unfortunately, as of now, no. (Since I don't have my laptop with me right now). However, why do you need a sample? Your own code can be made recursive by simple manipulation. I suggest you go through tree traversal once. You won't need a sample then.

Comment: How can I convert to a tree traversal, sorry not familiar with it

Comment: No actually. Hope you could help me.

Comment: Before getting into developing a script, you should first learn the tidbits of computer science like data structures and algorithms. That would help you a lot in a long run. I suggest you make a head start first and then jump to writing scripts and programs.

Answer (score 0):

95% based on @coder.in.me answer let me insert another code here that can resolve an issue I was facing with.

My issue was: "If you try to scrape a url like: https://www.americanexpress.com/hu-hu/, it will only keep the https://www.americanexpress.com/ part of it and scrape all the amex sites globally, but I don't need all the non-hungarian pages."

You just need to change the

```
if fields.netloc == self.domain:
```

code to

```
if fields.netloc == self.domain and (fields.path.startswith('/hu-hu') or fields.path.startswith('/en-hu')):
```

Here is the modified code:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlsplit, SplitResult
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class RecursiveScraper:
    ''' Scrape URLs in a recursive manner.
    '''
    def __init__(self, url):
        ''' Constructor to initialize domain name and main URL.
        '''
        self.domain = urlsplit(url).netloc
        self.mainurl = url
        self.urls = set()

    def preprocess_url(self, referrer, url):
        ''' Clean and filter URLs before scraping.
        '''
        if not url:
            return None
        fields = urlsplit(urljoin(referrer, url))._asdict() # convert to absolute URLs and split
        fields['path'] = re.sub(r'/$', '', fields['path']) # remove trailing /
        fields['fragment'] = '' # remove targets within a page
        fields = SplitResult(**fields)

        #if fields.netloc == self.domain:
        if fields.netloc == self.domain and (fields.path.startswith('/hu-hu') or fields.path.startswith('/en-hu')):
            # Scrape pages of current domain only
            if fields.scheme == 'http':
                httpurl = cleanurl = fields.geturl()
                httpsurl = httpurl.replace('http:', 'https:', 1)
            else:
                httpsurl = cleanurl = fields.geturl()
                httpurl = httpsurl.replace('https:', 'http:', 1)
            if httpurl not in self.urls and httpsurl not in self.urls:
                # Return URL only if it's not already in list
                return cleanurl

        return None


    def scrape(self, url=None):
        ''' Scrape the URL and its outward links in a depth-first order.
            If URL argument is None, start from main page.
        '''
        if url is None:
            url = self.mainurl

        print("Scraping {:s} ...".format(url))
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            self.urls.add(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
            for link in soup.findAll("a"):
                childurl = self.preprocess_url(url, link.get("href"))
                if childurl:
                    self.scrape(childurl)
        except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
            pass
        except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rscraper = RecursiveScraper('https://www.americanexpress.com/hu-hu/')
    rscraper.scrape()
```

Thanks!